# Obtener la cantidad de registros que se repiten por mes

Tags: sql, oracle

como obtengo la cantidad de registros que se repiten por mes, tengo la columna FEC_CREACION y la columna ID_REGISTRO

| FEC_CREACION | ID_REGISTRO |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 10:45:07.248 | A |
| 2021-12-22 11:52:59.199 | B |
| 2021-10-20 11:53:43.464 | A |
| 2021-09-19 12:12:02.225 | C |
| 2021-12-11 12:13:05.928 | B |
| 2021-11-12 12:14:36.850 | A |
| 2021-09-12 12:15:31.975 | C |
| 2021-08-11 12:16:35.787 | B |
| 2021-01-18 12:52:35.207 | B |
| 2021-02-17 12:55:23.784 | C |

Resultado esperado

| MES | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agarapa, sigue la query para la agrupación.
Para el resultado quee esperas tendrás que poner la query de tal manera que te retornes un PIVOT.

```
SELECT MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,FEC_CREACION,23))[MES],ID_REGISTRO,COUNT(ID_REGISTRO)[CANTIDAD]
FROM TEST
GROUP BY  MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,FEC_CREACION,23)),ID_REGISTRO
ORDER BY 1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]